# Question about 3-cycles?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Assume $n \ge 5$ and let $ H \triangleleft S_n$ be a normal subgroup. If $H$ contains at least one
$3$-cycle, prove $H = S_n$ or $H = A_n$.
I have no idea how to do this? I think i need to use the fact every element in $A_n$ is a product of
$3$-cycles.

Comment: Please note the $\LaTeX$ editing for further reference

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right. Just note that any two $3$-cycles are conjugate in $S_n$, so if the normal subgroup $H$ contains one $3$-cycle, it contains all of them.

More generally, two elements of $S_{n}$ are conjugate iff they have the same cycle structure.